# Getting input without a linebreak

Tags: c++, formatting, user-input

I'm writing a program which will be doing manipulation of matrices. I want the user to be able to enter data into a matrix by typing it in one row at a time. So it will first ask for the value in row: 1, column: 1. The user will type in the appropriate value, and then press enter, after which he will type in the value for row: 1, column: 2.

This is the trick: I want the console to not enter a new line when the user presses enter. Instead, I want it to simply insert a tab character. Is this possible?

Thanks so much.

Comment: If the user hits ENTER - how and why would it become something else? What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: This might invalidate using files as input. You also might want to provide alternate methods for input instead of manipulating the console, i.e. gui.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You'll need to use a console/terminal library, though. Ncurses for *nix, wincon (part of the Windows API; you can just #include `windows.h` to use it)... There are a lot of choices out there.

The actual algorithm will simply be checking the characters that are sent as key events/using the getkey() equivalents of the various libraries, outputting the inputted characters to the console if the key pressed is not ENTER but would still cause a character to be echoed to the screen (i.e. function keys, caps lock, shift, etc. wouldn't cause any echoing to the console or terminal window) and then outputting `\t` if the key pressed is indeed ENTER.

Answer (score 1):

Set the cursor position back up to the previous line. In Windows, you can use `SetConsoleCursorPosition()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you wanted, but you could get the same effect by using `getline` to obtain the row input all on one line, and then use `std::stringstream` to parse out the values.

```
 std::string row;
 getline(cin,row);
 std::stringstream ss(row);
 int j=0,i=currentrow;  //put this in a loop over your rows
 int input; //or float, double, whatever
 while(ss >> input)
 {
      mat[i][j] = input;
      j++;
 }
```